# Piping two audio FIFOs simultaneously, where one may not have data but takes priority, into a single FIFO output

Tags: shell-script, audio, fifo

I have a [snapcast](https://github.com/badaix/snapcast) audio server, which is configured to have three audio streams (fifos): *music*, *broadcast*, and *output*. My speakers play the audio from the *output* stream, and my music players pipe input into the *music* stream. I can successfully pipe the music into the output so that I hear the music on the speakers with the command: `cat /tmp/music > /tmp/output`

Now I want to implement an "override" feature where input from the *broadcast* stream causes the *output* to **instead** play the (alert) from the *broadcast*, temporarily ignoring the stream from *music* until the broadcast ends. However, most of the time */tmp/broadcast* is empty and has no input. Even a simple attempt to peek at the contents via `dd bs=1 count=1 if=/tmp/broadcast` hangs the terminal until there's data available in the broadcast. Therefore my attempts to do things like [merge streams](https://serverfault.com/questions/171095/how-do-i-join-two-named-pipes-into-single-input-stream-in-linux) is unsuccessful.

I have looked into [ffmpeg](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ffmpeg) and pulseaudio, but cannot figure out if such a "selective override" is possible. Ffmpeg further appears to [have bugs with multi-fifo input](https://superuser.com/questions/870335/combine-three-live-audio-streams-into-one-live-audio-stream). The ideal solution would also "sound nice," i.e., perhaps do a 1/4 second fade between the streams as the broadcast takes over.

**edit** Running `Ubuntu Desktop 18.04`. Whoops!

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]